# Two questions about one-hot encoding: drop first? and features with thousands of categories

Tags: categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, categorical-encoding

I have two questions about one-hot feature encoding:

(1) Is it considered a "best practice" to drop the first (or at least one) one-hot encoded feature when one-hot encoding, like you would when creating dummy variables for linear regression modelling in classical statistics?  It seems ML practitioners do this both ways; does any definitive guidance exist?

(2) What the best way is to handle the one-hot encoding of a categorical variable with thousands of features (around ~6000)?  This number is particularly high given the dataset is only about ~10 features wide before one-hot encoding.  Note that the categories are quite evenly distributed among the features.

Comment: Questions on stackexchange sites should be limited to one specific question. Your two questions already exist independently, e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27957/55122 and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10509/55122 (and spend a little time exploring Related/Linked questions, and also stats.stackexchange).

Answer (score 1):

One-hot (resp. one-cold) encoding creates co-linearity if all the features are used. Simply because the following relation **always** holds: $\sum_i  f_i = 1$.

So dropping one feature destroys the colinearity and it can have better results, since many models (esp. linear models) get confused with colinearities in the features.

If a categorical variable has many values, then one-hot (resp. one-cold) is not the best option to use and the results will suffer big time because of the curse of dimensionality.

Instead other encodings can be used like `LabelEncoder` which can in fact provide state-of-the-art results despite popular wisdom.

References:

1. [One-hot encoding + linear regression = multi-collinearity](https://geoffruddock.com/one-hot-encoding-plus-linear-regression-equals-multi-collinearity/)
2. [How to handle non ordinal Features like Gender,Language,Region etc? Ordinal Encoding or one-hot encoding?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/95105/how-to-handle-non-ordinal-features-like-gender-language-region-etc-ordinal-enco/95107#95107)